# Why did the HTTP transport appear garbled after I built my javaFX project by ANT

Tags: java, eclipse, http, ant

My development environment is as follows:

> OS:Win10
>
> IDE:Eclipse Oxygen
>
> JDK:1.8

My program can transport Chinese Characters correctly by HTTP when I debug and run on the eclipse. But after I building it by ant and then run it, HTTP transporting Chinese characters appear garbled.

No errors occurred during building.

It can also receive messages from ActiveMQ correctly.I can even log those characters correctly before transporting it.

Where's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.
It's irrelevant to ANT. My fault is do not set the Character Set before I transmitting data stream.

As follows:

```
String urlStr = "my url";
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
// Get OutputStream
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(httpConn.getOutputStream());
// transmitting data
String param = "my parameters";
// This statement is important
out.print(new String(param.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

Comment: I find that PrintWriter is unstable.I also encounter some messy Chinese characters.<br />I query some information and find<br /> `OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(httpConn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");`<br /> is the best choice.